# Compare and Combine Objects of same array

Tags: jolt

I want to iterate each object and map `system.myStringValue` with `value.myStringValue`

Can you provide spec for the same ?

I have provided the following input and output json. If any other things require form my side , let me know. I have tried with another spec but its not working for me as I want to combine email and phone in one object

Input :

```
[
  {
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": {
          "myStringValue": "email"
        },
        "value": {
          "myStringValue": "mobqa@tester.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "system": {
          "myStringValue": "phone"
        },
        "value": {
          "myStringValue": "123"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": {
          "myStringValue": "email"
        },
        "value": {
          "myStringValue": "john.doe@tester.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "telecom": [
      {
        "system": {
          "myStringValue": "email"
        },
        "value": {
          "myStringValue": "Gayle55@tester.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "email":"mobqa@tester.com",
      "phone":"123"
    },
    {
      "email":"john.doe@tester.com"
    },
    {
      "email":"Gayle55@tester.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "telecom": {
          "*": {
            "value": {
              "myStringValue": {
                // @ takes value of 'value.myStringValue' and puts it into 'users[&5]' occurence
                // @(3,system.myStringValue) go up four levels and then go to 'system.myStringValue'
                // value and grab it and put as key value to appropriate occurence of 'users' 
                "@": "users[&5].@(3,system.myStringValue)" 
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```